# command to add multiple “secondary groups” for a user in Solaris

Tags: solaris, group, usermod

I am trying to add 2 secondary groups for a user is Solaris system, but not able to do so. It only adds 1 secondary groups. I've done enough R&D, not sure what to do.

Below command I am using :

```
sudo usermod -g Primarygrp -G Secondarygrp1,Secondarygrp2 TJ252020
```

when I verify whether groups has been added or not, I use below command :-

```
id -Gn TJ252020
```

o/p I am getting- > `Primarygrp Secondarygrp1`

o/p I want -> `Primarygrp Secondarygrp1 Secondarygrp2`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`usermod(8)` manual on Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E72487/usermod-8.html), the group names should be prefixed by `+` to add them to the list of secondary groups.

I.e.,

```bsh
usermod -g Primarygrp -G +Secondarygrp1,Secondarygrp2 TJ252020
```

Without the `+`, the secondary groups are *set* to the first given group. The manual hints that it's only with a `+` or `-` prefix that the `-G` option takes a *list* of groups:

> When used with `usermod` or `rolemod` the `–A`, `–G`, `–K`, `–P`, and `–R` options may take a list of values to add or remove to the granted set using the `[+|-]` prefix.